# How can I specify the namespace for which controller to call in HtmlHelper.Action(string, string, object)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, html-helper

I have two controllers with identical names, one of which lives in the "Admin" area and one in the default area (which I believe resolves as an empty string for area).

The following call:

```
HtmlHelper.Action("Action", "DuplicateController", new { parameterValue = "test" } );
```

Doesn't appear to be able to resolve the difference between my `ProjectA.Controllers.DuplicateController` and `ProjectB.Controllers.DuplicateController`, even if I specify the area as "" by adding it as follows:

```
HtmlHelper.Action("Action", "DuplicateController", new { parameterValue = "test", area = "" } );
```

I know I should be able to resolve this by specifying a route when I register them on application startup, but is it possible to specify a fully-qualified namespace directly to the controller I know I need to call right in the action method?

e.g. something like the following would solve my problem:

```
HtmlHelper.Action("Action", "ProjectB.Controllers.DuplicateController", new { parameterValue = "test" } );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you suggested, I believe you'll have to add namespaces to the routes for both of your ambiguous controllers in your **RouteConfig.cs** file and your **AdminAreaRegistration.cs** file. For an example, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home).

So, you can either add the "**namespaces**" argument to the default route as in the above post or create a route for each "Duplicate" controller.

In your **RouteConfig.cs**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Duplicate",
    url: "Duplicate/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Duplicate", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MyMvcApplication.Controllers" }
);
```

And in your **AdminAreaRegistration.cs**:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Duplicate",
    "Admin/Duplicate/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Duplicate", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "MyMvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. I suppose the reasoning behind not allowing a namespace parameter in the helper method is that the routes should be responsible for all the mappings to controller actions, which I agree with in principle but is slightly less convenient in this case.