# namespace changing in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I have got the following run time error when I changed the namespace of the project. I would like to change a namespace because I want to use same name model with project namespace.

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Schedule'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Schedule' has found the following matching controllers:
Schedule.Schedule.ScheduleController
Schedule_Dt.ScheduleController
```

I want to remove namespance 'Schedule'. How can I do this? Thanks all.

Comment: You probably have more than one dll in your bin folder. Delete everything in bin and recompile. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home)

Comment: Areas can also be used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: see : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/11/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two.aspx