# Web Api controller thinks it is duplicated

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a webforms app, that has some Web Api controllers in it for integrations.
Two are working just fine. But Today I wanted to add another controller.

Should be simple enough, I add a new Web Api controller, add a little bit of code to it, and:

```
namespace MyApp.Web.App_Code
{
    public class AuthExportController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
 }
```

and when i call it at this url :

```
http://localhost:30978/MyApp/api/AuthExport
```

I get this error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Multiple types were found that match the controller named  
    'AuthExport'. This can happen if the route that services this request  
    ('api/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but 
    differing namespaces, which is not supported. The request for 'AuthExport' has found 
    the following matching controllers: MyApp.Web.App_Code.AuthExportController  
    MyApp.Web.App_Code.AuthExportController</ExceptionMessage>

    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>

    <StackTrace> at  
    System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessag
    e request) at   
    System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage 
    request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
    System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage  
    request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

As you can see, it is complaining about 2 controllers with the same name, but its the exact same controller. My other controllers work fine, just this particular one.

If it helps anything, this is my routing code in global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
}
```

Driving me mad!

**Update:**

Ok I managed to fix it, but I don't understand why, so if someone could explain it to me.
I compared my working controllers with my non working one.
Exact same signatures exactly, nothing different, same using statements, same inheritance etc etc.
One thing I did notice is the build action on the file.
Working file has a build action of "Content" and the non working has a build action of "Compile" . I change my non working one to "Content" and it works.

So now I am even more confused :) Happy that it works, but I don't like black magic in my systems

Comment: Do you use areas? If yes, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home) might be related

Comment: no areas. it is literally such a small vanilla app. a few web forms, and 3 controllers

Comment: Have you done any assembly-level manipulations, e.g. renamed the project along the way?

Comment: not on purpose or that i know of :) I updated the post with some new findings

Comment: That's kind of strange. Since controllers are code files, they should have 'Compile' build action. Could you, just for an experiment, change all controllers to that and see what happens?

Comment: if I take a working onw, and change it, i get the same error as above

Comment: Will try to get back and explain what's going on here later when I get my hands on a VS to play with. Unless someone explains this in a meanwhile!

Comment: I know this is old, but I want to answer the edit. The answer posted by @Dovydas Navickas below is most likely correct. The reason the project built when changing the build action is because by switching to "Content" the CS file is removed from the compiler, and is not built, and is not added to the project DLL, and no longer conflicts with the old DLLs in the bin folder. Sometimes I get weird errors like this and the first thing I do it delete the bin and obj folders from the project directory. Sometimes running a "Clean" will do the trick.

Answer (score 33):

**TL;DR:**

Delete `bin` folder in your project's file directory and build your project again.

**Explanation:**

I just encountered this error while renaming an existing project and changing namespaces for it and this is what happened:

Let's say projects' name was `FirstName` and I wanted to rename it to `SecondName`.

- I built project which compiled everything and generated `bin/Debug/FirstName.dll` files
- I renamed the project to `SecondName`
- I refactored the namespace
- Built and ran the project
- This generated `bin/Debug/SecondName.dll`

When project was ran, IIS Express simply took all of the `.dll` files and loaded them into memory, which happened to include both `FirstName.dll` and `SecondName.dll`.

As you might already understood, `FirstName.dll` and `SecondName.dll` had the same classes and methods, but with a different namespaces!
Therefore, as both of DLLs were loaded into memory by IIS, WebApi routing mechanism was finding both of namespaces with same controllers and action names.

And there you have it. No voodoo magic after all :)

Comment: Accepting an answer as a correct one would be nice of yours :)

Comment: Great clear answer @Dovydas - saved me a heap of time troubleshooting. Crudler, please accept the answer or add a comment to why it's not working for you

Comment: Upvote for suggestion to delete Bin, that is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Upvote for this, it just fixed the same problem I was having - not sure why you have not had this answer accepted!

Comment: This drove me crazy whole day.  Got struck in a same scenario of name changing and was getting this error until i came here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to change names of references, projects and solution and after that I had this problem for days.
When I looked for solution, I got the answer everywhere that remove your **/bin** folder contents and try rebuilding solution, I did that but this didn't solve my problem.I then created a separate solution added all these projects in that solution with **bin** folder empty, and build the solution still didn't solve my problem.
Here are the things I had to do to get back on track:

- First changed assembly names from **Project/Properties/**
- Cleared **/bin** , **/bin/debug** folder
- Cleared **/obj/debug/(.dll, .cache, temporary created files)** of each project.

Then rebuild the solution and finally got it solved.
If removing only /bin doesn't work out then try this.