# Area routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I am a bit confused with the area routing. I created an area called Backbone. I have my default controller, views and models as well.

```
http://localhost:46870/
```

gives me the following error :

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'home'. This can happen if     
the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify   
namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case,  
register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 
'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'home' has found the following matching controllers:
LearnJavascript.Areas.BackBone.Controllers.HomeController
LearnJavascript.Controllers.HomeController
```

Here is backbone route(This came with scaffolding, I did not make any changes):

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "BackBone_default",
            "BackBone/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Default route (This came with scaffolding, I did not make any changes):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I was thinking that unless the url starts with

```
http://localhost:46870/Backbone
```

the backbone area home will not be called. So, why is routing confused on this.

Most confusing part was when I called this url :

```
http://localhost:46870/home/index
```

It shows me the same error message. Why is MVC routing so much confused on this.

Iam using VS2013 and MVC5.

Comment: even in different areas you can't have 2 controllers with the same name.

Comment: I thought having the same controller names was the main purpose of having an area.

Comment: Please check  
[Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home

Comment: @HamidBahmanabady I added the namespace to the global route and it started working fine. thanks.

Comment: @MattBodily We can have the same controller name in areas. That is one of the main purpose of having areas. I just created another area and double checked it. :)

Comment: "I was thinking that unless the url starts with [Backbone] the backbone area home will not be called." It's actually the opposite. If you use the URL with the `Backbone` prefix, then there's no ambiguity, and the right controller is called. But, otherwise, all "Home" controllers could potentially match, therefore you need to specify a namespace on the route to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Using the backbone prefix clears the ambiguity. But when a url is called without the backbone prefix, i think it is very clear (at least to me) that it should fall to the route outside the area. Why is MVC confused about this. Its very clear that if I want an area controller, I will be calling with the area name prefix.

Comment: Not necessarily. See, the physical path of the controller does not matter. Once they're compiled there's no physical path anymore. Now, they will likely be in different namespaces, but when routing framework kicks in it simply requests "controllers", basically anything that inherits from `Controller` and searches these to find an action to handle the route. Your area route dictates a specific namespace to search within, so there's no ambiguity, but your default route doesn't, so any "Home" controller, regardless of what namespace it's in matches.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Nice point. Justifies the need for namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the correct answer from HamidBahmanabady.

I added the namespace to the global route and it started working fine.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Test.Controllers"}
```

and

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "BackBone_default",
            "BackBone/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Test.Areas.Backbone.Controllers" }
```

Comment: hi, I've tried yours code, but it comes an error again                                                                      The request for 'Health' has found the following matching controllers:
Appname.Areas.Admin.Controllers.HealthController
Appname.Controllers.HealthController, **What should I do?**

Answer (score 1):

try this,

In route.config

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "Test.Controllers"}
```

and Admin section --> AdminAreaRegistration.cs

```
  context.MapRoute(
        "BackBone_default",
        "BackBone/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "Test.Areas.Backbone.Controllers" }
```