# Controller namespace not routing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

So I am using MVC 5, and is getting this error. This is because I have two areas and they both have a controller with the same name and same method name.

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'controller1'. 
This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not 
specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. 
If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of 
the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
```

So I understand that I need to add name spaces to my routing. So in `Route.config.cs` I added this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
   namespaces: new[] { "webApp.Controllers" }
 );
```

Then in the `application_start()` function in `global.asax` I added `ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("webApp.Controllers");`

Then in my areas, where my error is coming from. I have 2 areas, admin and myportal. Both have a AreaRegistration.cs file. In AdminAreaRegistration.cs I have this added

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new[] { "webApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

In MyPortalAreaRegistration.cs I have this added

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "MyPortal_default",
            "MyPortal/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "webApp.Areas.MyPortal.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

From the client side I am making a post call

```
 const otherParams = {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(product),
        method: 'POST'
    };
    console.log(otherParams);
    const response = await fetch('/Item/GetDetailPageURL', otherParams)
        .then(response => {
            response.json();
            console.log(response);
            window.open(response.url, "_blank");
        })
        .then(data => console.log(data));
```

From what I understand this is all I needed to get it work, but it is still complaining about the namespace. Am I misunderstanding/ missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to change your `RouteConfig.cs`

All you need to do is to register your area (inside the area folder):

In [this example](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/area-in-asp.net-mvc), the area name is `admin`. You need to write your area registration code inside `adminAreaRegistration.cs` file which is inside `admin` folder:

[image]

```
public class adminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "admin_default",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And then add `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` to your `Global.asax.cs`

Answer (score 0):

Besides `area registration` like Hooman Bahreini said, try to setup your default name spaces as well in the application start.

1. Try this

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);     
        // in you application start register your default or whatever makes sense Portal Controllers     
  ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("webApp.Areas.MyPortal.Controllers"); 
    }
```

2. TRUST ME ON THIS -- go to your `bin` folder and blow away any old dll's "bin" folder completely manually. Sometimes there are stale dll's and **don't get cleaned**
3. your routes seem fine, but double check your routes with this answer on [routes...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274359/6085193)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/):

```
[RoutePrefix(“reviews”)]
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
```

Somewhere else:

```
[RoutePrefix(“otherreviews”)]
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
```