# @Html.Action and Controllers with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-controller

While creating a Plugin for a MVC site, I'm facing an issue about controller resolution.

Here are all the routes that concern the current context :

```
routes.MapRoute("Route1",
    "Admin/Product/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", area = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Plugin.Controllers" }
)

routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "Admin", id = "" },
    new[] { "Admin.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Public.Controllers" }
);
```

There are 3 ProductController classes in the entire solution :

- Plugin.Controllers.ProductController (inherits from the Admin one)
- Admin.Controllers.ProductController
- Public.Controllers.ProductController

In my view "/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" (i.e. the "Index" action of the HomeController without any area) I have the following code :

```
@Html.Action("HomepageProducts", "Product")
```

It refers to the action "HomepageProducts" of the **Public.Controllers**.ProductController.

MVC looks for the plugin controller instead of the public one and throws the following exception :

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'HomepageProducts' was not found on controller '**Plugin.Controllers.ProductController**'.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName) +291
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +31
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__9() +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3() +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +64
>      System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +71
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1436
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Erreur d'exécution de la demande enfant pour le gestionnaire 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.]
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3428452
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +76
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +29
>      System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +24
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +464
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +83
>      System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName) +10
>      ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Path\To\My\Project\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:14

If this helps, the solution use Autofac.MVC5...
Any help/comment/idea is welcome.

Am I missing something or only the routes are implied in controllers resolution ?

**UPDATE**

When browsing the "Admin" area all actions are well performed, the plugin and the admin controllers works fine.

If I comment the plugin route, the error is not thrown anymore. Of course my plugin controller is not called anymore.

```
// routes.MapRoute("Route1",
//     "Admin/Product/{action}/{id}",
//     new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", area = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
//     new[] { "Plugin.Controllers" }
// )
```

So I guess the issue is due to the plugin route, the plugin controller itself or the way the route is resolved by MVC ?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to uncomment all my routes and specify area in @Html.Action() as follow:

```
@Html.Action("HomepageProducts", "Product", new { area = "" })
```

But MVC ignore the area and try to load the Plugin controller...

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'HomepageProducts' was not found on controller '**Plugin.Controllers**.ProductController'.]

Comment: In your controller, `Plugin.Controllers.ProductController`.. do you have an `ActionResult` method named `HomepageProducts` that returns a `View`?

Comment: No I don't. Only the public one have this action

Comment: I would assume this is happening because in your Route.config, specifically for `Route 1`.. you're calling `@Html.Action("HomepageProducts", "Product")` which is going to the `Product` Controller, which matches the URL you provided in `Route 1`..

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. The HomeController is a "public" one (not in an area) and the Html.Action() doesn't specify any "area". Why is MVC looking for a controller associated to an area route ?

Comment: Are you using Area for `Admin`? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home

Comment: Yes, my plugin controller and the admin controller use an area as you can see in the routes of my post. I also defined namespaces for each route.

Comment: try @Html.Action("HomepageProducts", "Product", new {Area=""})

Comment: Good suggestion. That's what I've tried in my **UPDATE 2**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm definitely sure I miss something but I bypass my issue by register each Plugin.ProductController action routes I've overridden from the Admin one.

```
routes.MapRoute("Route1",
    "Admin/Product/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", area = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Plugin.Controllers" }
)

//...becomes...

routes.MapRoute("Product.Action1",
    "Admin/Product/Action1/{id}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Action1", area = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Plugin.Controllers" }
)

routes.MapRoute("Product.Action2",
    "Admin/Product/Action2/{id}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Action2", area = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Plugin.Controllers" }
)

//...
```

All works fine now. With this, I'm able to derive controllers.