# Multiple types were found that match at different area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I have bellow link when the user click on it ,it should be load Article view that is in current area.
picture
[image]

But when I click on this link I get this error
[image]

but I've checked my routeconfig and my admin area and I have used namespases as well.
In my routeconfig
[image]
In my Admin area
[image]

I can not figure out what problem is ,I've used namespaces but it doesn't work.

when I click on this link `<a href="/Article/Details/2">`
I get the Error but my route config like these
In my routeconfig:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new[] { "IdentitySample.Controllers" }
            );
```

And in Admin area config:

```
       public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Administrator_default",
                "Administrator/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                 new[] { "tadvinhesab.Areas.Administrator.Controllers" }

            );
   
        }
```

and I ended up with this link

```
   <a  href="@Url.Action("Details", "Article", new {  Area = "IdentitySample",id = @article.id }, "https")">
```

but `Area = "IdentitySample"` cause the link dose not work when i put in new array.
And in another shot I changed it this way
                               `<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Article", new { Area = "", id = @article.id})" class="myCssClass">link text</a>`
but my problem in still the same

Comment: copy and paste the code, please don't take screenshots as it makes it very difficult for us to go through it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to change the namespace:

```cs
namespaces: new[] { "IdentitySample.Controllers" }
```

you should change it to something like this:

```cs
namespaces: new[] { "tadvinhesab.Controllers" }
```

also in this link, you can see a lot of other possible solutions to solve this:

[Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home)

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours working around, I finally realized that I use identity sample project that default namespace was `identitySmaple` but in some sections of my project I used my own namespace with a different names from `identitySmaple` that causes this weird problem.

with the help of (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), I replaced all `identitySmaples` to my namespace then It works properly.