# Why is ASP.NET MVC returning multiple types matching a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm trying to set up a versioned API using ASP.NET MVC4. `Global.asax.cs` calls a method in my project `WebApiConfig.Register` with `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`. Here's what the code looks like for `WebApiConfig.Register` looks like:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    CreateRoute(
        routes: config.Routes,
        name: "Root",
        routeTemplate: "api",
        defaults: new { },
        constraints: new { },
        namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.Controllers.Api" },
    );

    CreateRoute(
        routes: config.Routes,
        name: "API",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get" },
        constraints: new { },
        namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.Controllers.Api" },
    );

    CreateRoute(
        routes: config.Routes,
        name: "API v2",
        routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get" },
        constraints: new { },
        namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.Controllers.Api.v2" },
    );
}

private static void CreateRoute(HttpRouteCollection routes, string name, string routeTemplate, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
{
    var defaultsDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(defaults);
    var constraintsDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(constraints);
    var dataTokensDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(new { Namespaces = namespaces, UseNamespaceFallback = false });
    var route = routes.CreateRoute(routeTemplate, defaultsDictionary, constraintsDictionary, dataTokensDictionary);
    routes.Add(name, route);
}
```

I have two controllers named `UsersController`, one at `MyApp.Controllers.Api.UsersController` and one at `MyApp.Controllers.Api.v2.UsersController`. When I make a request like `POST /api/users/Login`, I get the response `500 Multiple types were found that match the controller names 'users'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/{controller}/{action}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.\r\n\r\nThe request for 'users' has found the following matching controllers:\r\nMyApp.Controllers.Api.v2.UsersController\r\nMyApp.Controllers.Api.UsersController`

As you can see, I'm specifically setting namespaces on the routes, and I'm setting `UseNamespaceFallback` to `false` to avoid collisions, but they're happening anyway. How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like your answer could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home

Comment: Nope. The answer on that question is to use namespaces when declaring routes. I'm already doing that. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: Try moving the first route config which is generic, at the last of all specific routes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and I'm still getting the same error. Then I tried commenting out routes to see which one is causing the problem, and I can confirm that it's the route with the name `API`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this isn't mentioned more places, but apparently [System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerSelector.cs) (which, as the name suggests, resolves controllers by default) doesn't support the `Namespaces` data token (or any other way of restricting namespace). I was able to fix my routing by adding a Nuget reference to [WebApiContrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebAPIContrib/) and configuring my API to use [`NamespaceHttpControllerSelector`](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Selectors/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs) in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

Comment: The `ControllerTypeCache` for mvc is replaced by [System.Web.Mvc/ControllerTypeCache.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerTypeCache.cs)

Answer (score 0):

`MyApp.Controllers.Api.v2.UsersController` is in the namespace `MyApp.Controllers.Api`.  So there are two `UsersController` in the same namespace.

Using `UseNamespaceFallback` simply means that if there is no `UsersController` in the `v2` namespace, to check the previous namespaces so settings it's value has no affect on the non-`v2` namespace, the namespace that has the problem.

You should be able to update the first ones namespace to:

```
MyApp.Controllers.Api.v1.UsersController
// and then
MyApp.Controllers.Api.v2.UsersController
```

Then you can update the namespace parametere:

```
namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.Controllers.Api.v1" },
```

Comment: I tried renaming the namespace `MyApp.Controllers.Api.v2` to `MyApp.Controllers.Foobar` (so it doesn't start with the other namespace), and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: And changed the namespaces value in the route?