# Changed namespace of a controller, stuck old reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Question Background:**

I have an MVC 4 app whos original `namespace` was under 'BootStrap'. I have now changed the `namespace` to 'FMFCSite'.

**The Issue:**

When I now run my site I'm getting an ASP.NET error as shown:

**Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
BootStrap.Controllers.HomeController
FMFCSite.Controllers.HomeController**

I only have one controller called 'Home' and that is under the FMFC namespace. **Where do I need to be looking to remove the other reference under Bootstrap?**

Comment: You probably have two assemblies in your bin folder after you deployed, so you want to build clean, and deploy with remove extra files checkbox checked (assuming you renamed the assembly)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689793/namespace-change-multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-ho?rq=1