# Multiple types found routing error even though a namespace is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, routes

related:

[Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home)

[Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home' - In two different Areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788014/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home-in-two-differ?rq=1)

---

Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'FW'.

> The request for 'FW' has found the following matching controllers:
>
> app.Controllers.Admin.FWController
>
> app.Areas.Manage.Controllers.FWController

I tried the suggestions from those related links. I attempted to differentiate the controllers by using different namespaces:

global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
 new string[] { "app.Controllers" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default_Admin_Top", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
 new string[] { "app.Controllers.Admin" }
);
```

in the manage area `ManageAreaRegistration`

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
 context.MapRoute(
  "Manage_default",
  "Manage/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new string[] { "app.Areas.Manage.Controllers" }
 );
}
```

I also looked in the `bin` folder for an old version but there was only the current one.

What am I missing? It seems like this should work.

The issue appears to revolve around the fact that I gave my controller its own namespace without it being in its own area:

```
namespace app.Controllers.Admin
{
 public class FWController : Controller{}
}
```

Removing the `.Admin` from the namespace here will remove the collision and also the error, but I do not fully understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try and rearrage your rotes like this. The problem might be arising because `app.Controllers.Admin` lies in `app.Controller`

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default_Admin_Top", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
 new string[] { "app.Controllers.Admin" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
 new string[] { "app.Controllers" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks similar to an issue which i have faced lately.

according to your scenario and having experienced the same issue, i suspect the problem would be the naming convention with controllers. Say for instance, your application has a controller named `FWController` in your root structure before re-structuring/maintaining your code in separate areas. when your application starts, the `Application_Start()` method inside `Global.asax` file registers route to route collection table (one of the core features of MVC 3 pattern) which maintain your incoming request when an action method executes inside a controller.

problem arises when you have a controller with same name like in your case `FWController` and directory structure of area somehow mimics the root directory just as you see in one of the referenced urls.

I implemented the similar solution as one of the URL justifies, i.e.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },   //Parameter defaults               
  new []{"MyProject.WWW.Controllers"}
);
```

i did not touch my area registration.cs file at all.

When you rename the namespace, your routing starts pointing to the `app.Controllers.FWController` (not in `app.Areas.Manage.Controllers.FWController`), which resolved the conflict that was occurring before because you specified this in your `Global.asax`

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new string[] { "app.Controllers" }
);
```

that request also neglects the `MapRoute` that contains `.admin` namespace. That could possibly be the reason i believe. Hope it helped you.