# ASP.Net MVC 4 - Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-4

Just created a new MVC 4 project and copied over some areas from an MVC 3 project. I have double checked all my web.configs and arearegistration.cs. My configs all point to the correct versions of razor and MVC and my routes.MapRoute signature includes the correct namespace parameters, I also checked and made sure my IIS pool was not hosting more than one MVC app.

my Global.asax file...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new string[] { "MVCProject.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

my area registration files...

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "MVCProject.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
```

and ...

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Terminator_default",
            "Terminator/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "MVCProject.Web.Areas.Terminator.Controllers" }
        );
```

I have checked everything I know to check to fix this
, the correct dll's area loaded as well...

Comment: Do you use a custom dependency / controller resolver? Special care has to be taken when you implement a custom resolver (ie for Windsor) and use Areas also. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092589/having-issue-with-multiple-controllers-of-the-same-name-in-my-project

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out what was going on. I'll answer my own question in hopes that it helps someone else.

Typically when you create a new MVC project in VS 2010 you get what the template gives you as far as name spaces and a stubbed out home controller or two. I like to break my MVC app up into the usual layers (Data, Model & Service) with each layer being in it's own project. Then I rename my web project to append .web to the project name and name space "MyWebProject.Web".

The template created the app prior to me renaming the web project and stubbed out a home controller for me. The home controller created by the template was in the MyWebProject.Controllers namespace, my routes.MapRoutes() used MyWebProject.Web.Controllers as a parameter.

Once I moved my stubbed out controllers created by the template into the MyWebProject.Web.Controllers namespace it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Another plausible cause of this issue could be found below:***

[multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home/18979616#18979616)