# Asp.net MVC: Multiple areas having same controller and action method - Html.BeginForm with Post action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm using areas feature of Asp.net MVC.

Two different areas with same name controllers:

[image: Two area with same controller name]

AdminAreaRegistration.cs
[image]

UserAreaRegistration.cs
[image]

I would like to have a form that posts to the following method:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "Login", 
 new { area = "", model = this.Model, returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] },      
 FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "frmLogin" }))
```

But i got an error:

[image]

How can i solve it with multiple areas have same name controller and post method using Html.BeginForm()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having issue with multiple controllers of the same name in my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092589/having-issue-with-multiple-controllers-of-the-same-name-in-my-project)

Comment: not duplicate, its concern for Html.BeginForm(). Have you any idea how to fixed it?

Comment: I have already register route for all controller and action with different areas, but i would like to call post method with passing form data

Comment: Please show me your RegisterRoutes method in RouteConfig and also AdminAreaRegistraction.cs and UserAreaRegistraction.cs.

Comment: register namespaces in web config

Comment: Pragnesh >> I have update question content as per your requirement.

Comment: vishal>> I have already register all route in UserAreaRegistration.cs and AdminAreaRegistration.cs

Comment: Simoco>> We can take same name controller with different areas.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the area in the HTML helper tag as below

your area name must be defined in the HTML helper.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "Login", 
new { area = "YOUR AREA NAME", model = this.Model, returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] },      
FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "frmLogin" }))
```

Comment: I have already trying with same syntax, but i did't got any solution :(