# MVC C# Controller Conflict (site front with area admin)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, asp.net-mvc-areas, areas

I can not figure this out.

How to solve the problem?

AdminAreaReistration cs

```
        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "CMSAdmin_default",
            "CMSAdmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

RouteConfig

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How is the error being generated? Are you attempting to go to a particular URL or are you trying to generate a URL with something like `Url.Action`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to error image, you may use different namespaces when declaring an area into `RegisterArea` to avoid naming conflict between default route and area route:

`AdminAreaRegistration.cs`

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "CMSAdmin_default",
        "CMSAdmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "cms.site.Areas.CMSAdmin.Controllers" } // Insert area namespace here
    );
}
```

`RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "cms.site.Controllers" } // Insert project namespace here
    );
}
```

Possible causes from `Multiple types were found that match the controller name` error:

1) Using same controller name with different areas (this is likely your current issue),

2) Renaming project namespace/assembly name (delete old project name DLL file inside /bin directory then clean and rebuild again),

3) Conflict between references with same name but different versions (remove older reference then refactor).

References:

[Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842293/multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-home)

[Having issue with multiple controllers of the same name in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092589/having-issue-with-multiple-controllers-of-the-same-name-in-my-project)

Comment: Thank you.
You are the only one who responds very clearly to this issue. :)

My problem in article 1